# What is the definition of a sharp obstruction related with symplectic embedding?

Tags: geometry, symplectic-geometry, contact-topology

What is the definition of a sharp obstruction related with symplectic embedding?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Without context it's hard to say, but for quantitative results in symplectic geometry (e.g. Gromov non-squeezing) sharpness means the same thing it does in inequalities. For instance, if $B_R^{n}$ symplectically embeds inside $B_r^{2}\times \Bbb R^{2n-2}$ then $R \leq r$ is an example of a sharp inequality as there exists an easy embedding when $R\leq r$.

Comment: What PVAL said is exactly correct. The obstruction is sharp if it characterizes when the embedding is possible.